# Nagios: How to allow a non-admin user the correct permissions to be able to acknowledge alerts?

Tags: nagios

Sometimes there are alerts which are not so urgent and can wait for the next morning until they are taken cared of.
During these times, the NOC team keeps getting alerts regarding the problematic issues but have no access to acknowledge them.

I've went through the `cgi.cfg` file which controls user permissions in Nagios but I couldn't find the directive which talks about alert ack's even though I read the whole file.

Can you please point me to the correct directive to set?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you override the behavior by adding them to `authorized_for_<whatever>` options in cgi.cfg, **users can only see or interact with hosts/services for which they are contacts**.

Users also get alerts for hosts/services for which they are contacts. So, if a user gets an alert, that user can also acknowledge the alert.

All of this depends on your users logging into the web interface with their own usernames, which **must match the contact names**. This works well with LDAP authentication, for example.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't (as far as I know) an authorisation specifically for acks.

If you want the NOC to be able to ack everything then add them to the authorised_for_all_service_commands and possibly the host equivalent. This means they'll also be able to disable active checks etc.

I don't know if this is different in nagios 4.x.